# Why not True == True:

Tags: python

The last point of the style guide http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008

reads ...

Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==.

Why?

Edit
Just to make it clear what im asking (and it's indicative of the problem itself), when you write

```
if something:
    print "something is true"
```

You are doing an implicit conversion to a boolean which may or may not work depending on what true means. IMHO this form of programming is discouraged because of the side effects it can cause.

```
numberOfApples = -1
if numberOfApples:
    print "you have apples" # is not what is intended.

if numberOfApples == True:
    print "you have apples" # is also not what is intended.

iHaveApples = numberOfApples > 0
if iHaveApples is True:    # Edit:  corrected this.. the "is" is better than the ==
  print  "you have apples" # is correct.
```

Implicit conversions disguise logical errors. So why does the style guide encourage this?

Comment: Im beginning to think that the best style for boolean testing is labeled the worst in the Style guide.
if numberOfApples is True: 
will be clear that numberOfApples is not a bool.

Comment: Then what you really want is compare if x is of type bool() and if it is, if it's True or False

Comment: @PedroWerneck Exactly. So the style guide is wrong to say that the worst way to to test a bool is  if bool_type is [True|False]: because its actually the best way

Answer (score 7):

It means that you should write

```
if greeting:
```

Instead of:

```
if greeting == True:
```

Similarly, you shouldn't write this either:

```
if (greeting == True) == True:
```

The extra tests are redundant and don't add any value to the code, so they should be removed.

Comment: It's amazing how people don't get booleans. For instance "bool Predicate() { if (condition) return true; else return false; }" - What? This can written simply "bool Predicate() { return condition; }" !

Comment: Unfortunatly, when the language support other values for truehood/falsehood, the exact statement you use can drastically change the meaning of your program... Special functions like `__eq__`, `__nonzero__` and `__len__` only make things worse (useful, yes, but problematic sometimes)

Comment: @mgibsonbr You can just use `bool` to force the value to a boolean.

Comment: @Marcin cool, but what good is it for? If you want to take `__nonzero__` and `__len__` into account, just follow the style guide and you'll be fine. If you do not, you have no choice but using `is` or `isinstance` or `type`. If you want to normalize the value, then I agree it's useful. (*Edit:* I think I know what you mean: that `bool(stmt)`, `bool(stmt) is True` and `bool(stmt) == True` all behave correctly, right? That's true indeed)

Comment: @mgibsonbr No my point is that if you are worried about "other values...can drastically change the meaning of your program", you can simply use `bool(stmt)` if you need to return the truth-value, and you will be guaranteed a boolean.

Comment: @Marcin oh, ok, thanks for the clarification. That's what I meant by "normalize the value", and I agree it's really useful for that task, in special when dealing with `or` or `and`. For some examples of the drastic changes I referred to, see the code in the end of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10222759/520779)

Comment: @Dr_Asik I didn't say I dont get booleans. Im asking why should it be a style directive?

Comment: @PeterMoore I wasn't talking about you in particular, sorry if that seemed like a personal attack.

Comment: @Dr_Asik You never mentioned my mother so I never thought it was personal :-)  What may be the best answer is labeled as the worst in the style guide "if 30.1 is True" seems to be less likely to be misinterpreted by conversion.

Comment: @PeterMoore as my comment below shows, that happens by design, not by chance. But if your goal is to explicitly test whether a value is the boolean `True`, then you are totally correct, using `is` is the way to go, no matter what the style guide says (though a more explicit way of saying it would be `id(value) == id(True)`: this states clearly that what you want is a reference comparison, with no type conversion or DWIM behavior of any kind). Anyway, I disagree with the style guide, `==` is much worse than `is`, for the reasons explained in my answer below.

Comment: Quote from the style guide: "But **most importantly**: know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the style guide just doesn't apply". In my opinion, if you explicitly wish to test *only* for True (rare, but can happen), use `if x is True:`. If you want to test for truthiness, use `if x:`. I can't think of a valid use case for `if x == True:` though.

Comment: @MarkByers Yes Mark. All im saying is the Style guide is talking about testing booleans. Not other types. So if unknown_type: is not a test of a boolean and can get you into trouble. Testing with the "is" is better. unknown_type is [True|False] will yield false in all conditions except if type is a boolean and the boolean matches your desired state. So the style guide is incorrect to say its the worst.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's redundant.

```
if hasChildren:
```

is the same as

```
if hasChildren == True:
```

but is briefer and easier to read.

Comment: if numberOfChildren: print True will return true if the answer is non zero. Even if its negative. Implicit conversion to boolean has side effects and is usually discouraged. The style guide is however encouraging implicit conversion to bool.

Comment: @PeterMoore, You're misunderstanding the style guide. `if numberOfChildren > 0:` is perfectly pythonic, however `if (numberOfChildren > 0) == True:` is not.

Comment: @Bago I totally agree if(numberOfChildern > 0) == True: is redundant because the comparator ">" will explicitly make the left side a bool type. However the if unknown_type: contrary to the style guide is less safe than testing with the "is". Testing bool "is" bool is better than if bool: or if bool == bool: because you will not get a false True due to the overloading of Truth that happens in python. Which is all im actually saying.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the point of a style guide is to standardise some common constructs, in a way that makes sense, so you won't end up with wildly disparating statements that ultimately do the same thing. More, the unusual forms might suggest that the programmer had some reason to do things a different way, maybe he was trying to achieve something different than what the statement looks like.

If you want to test the truehood/falsehood of a statement, just use the statement itself or precede it by `not`. If you must ensure the statement evaluates to `True` or `False` (not just a truthy/falsy value), you could use `statement is True` - though the style guide discourages it - or maybe check its type (using `isinstance`). But that's usually bad design, you should avoid that unless you have a pretty good reason to do so.

Using `statement == True` is dangerous for many reasons: 1) only work with `True`, failing with other "truthy" values (like `[1]`); 2) might produce unexpected results if the value returned by statement redefines `__eq__`; 3) might produce different results if the order of the arguments is changed, etc. Note that just using the statement may also return a different value for truehood/falsehood if the value implements `__nonzero__` or `__len__`, but for regular usage that's usually not a problem.

Some examples showing how messed up things can be if you deviate from the style:

```
if True: print True # True
if 1: print True    # True
if [1]: print True  # True

True is True # True
1 is True    # False
[1] is True  # False

True == True # True
1 == True    # True
[1] == True  # False
```

*Edit:* some more:

```
if 1: print True # True
if 2: print True # True

1 == True # True
2 == True # False

1 is True # False
2 is True # False
```

**Update:** as @Marcin pointed out, you can use `bool` to coerce a value to `True`/`False`, guaranteeing that only those values will be present. The result of that function is consistent to the default truehood/falsehood of the value (so `__nonzero__` and `__len__` is taken into account). Some examples:

```
if bool(1): print True # True
bool(1) == True        # True
bool(1) is True        # True

if bool(2): print True # True
bool(2) == True        # True
bool(2) is True        # True

1 or 2              # 1
1 and 2             # 2
bool(1) or bool(2)  # True
bool(1) and bool(2) # True

bool(1) == bool(2)  # True
bool(1) is bool(2)  # True
```

Comment: I appreciate your comments and this is a explicit conversion. My beef (as it where) is where the style guide encourages what i think as sloppy side effect ridden implicit conversion over tight explicit conversion. I dont consider (for example) a container to be True or False. To me it doesnt make much sense to overload a truth like that to mean its not empty.

Comment: That is subjective IMHO, some languages (ex. Java) encourage tight explicit conversion with the rationale that it reduces the window for error, others encourage DWIM behavior with the goal of increasing the language expressiveness. Treating numbers as false/true if they are zero/non-zero is a common practice in C, treating empty containers (lists, strings, sets) as false is common in Lisp, and both practices have advantages and disadvantages. What's important is that a language implements the chosen strategy consistently (contrast JavaScript, for example, where "" is false but [] is true).

Comment: I dont think that using the bool(unknown_type) will have the same effect as using the unknown_type "is" [False|True] for example if T = -1 then it is not True by convention of 0 = False 1 = True and type is a bool. So the test gives false results in the test of state of a bool.

Comment: Of course not, what I meant is `if unknown_type:` will satisfy the condition iff `bool(unknown_type)` is True (i.e. the logic of `bool` is the same logic as the one used in `if`, `while` etc). Also, the convension for numbers in Python is 0 = False, anything else = True (I believe it also holds for C and other languages that auto-coerce numbers to booleans), so `if -1:` will enter, and `bool(-1)` is True. But both `-1 is True` and `-1 is False` will return `False` (since -1 is not True or False, -1 is -1).

Answer (score 1):

In sort:

```
# A, Good:
if numberOfApples > 0:
    print "you have apples"

# B, Also good:
iHaveApples = numberOfApples > 0
if iHaveApples:
  print  "you have apples"

# C, Bad:
iHaveApples = numberOfApples > 0
if iHaveApples == True:
  print  "you have apples"
```

Why would you ever pick C over A or B?

Update:

I think you're sweating bullets over some corner cases, but if those corner cases matter in your project use the appropriate comparison. In general we do know something about the type of `iHaveApples`, for example we know that it's the result of a comparison using `>`. It's reasonable, and good practice I believe, to use that information in your code. If you're asking, "what if I think it's a bool and it turns out to be an int or something else." Than I would say you have a bug in your code, you should find it, fix it, and write a test in case you make the same mistake again. Don't rely on python to find your mistakes at runtime.

I'll assert, and leave up to you to prove if you want, that `if iHaveApples:` behaves exactly the same, but runs faster, as `if iHaveApples is True:` when you know for sure that `iHaveApples` is a bool. Lastly I'll give an example of when `is` would result in undesired behavior, at least in my opinion.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> totalApples = numpy.sum([1, 2, 3]) == 6
>>> totalApples
True
>>> totalApples is True
False
```

I'll let you figure out why that doesn't work if you want (hint, check `type(totalApples)`).

Comment: I think that C is also not quite right but it should be "is" instead of ==. so if iHaveApples is True will be more true than any other way of expressing it. I definitely dont think it should be the way the style guide sugests.

Comment: B by the way is not good unless you know for sure you are comparing a boolean. How can you know that the type is a bool in the if statement? The implicit conversion problem only raises its head if you think your comparing a bool and its not a bool. That is why i picked numberOfApples at -1 for my example. and also why i made a boolean with the > comparitor. The style guide is talking about testing boolean values explicitly and its test is less than safe.

Comment: I dont have numpy and it failed when i tried to install it. So what is the type?

Comment: And please be mindful of what im saying. for "boolean" comparisons there seems to be an comparitor which is "is" and that is what the style guide is saying is the worst because its talking about booleans and not truth value. comparing the truth is not the same as comparing the result of a bool. You can forgo the type check for speed reasons (which is 17% faster which is 50 nano sec on my machine). But again that is not the point.